# Convert Row Data into Columns using SQL on MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Good day,

Initially I had a table that works like this:

Table1

```
PartSN Test Data
Part1 Test1 20
Part1 Test2 23
```

I could convert the test into column using MAX IIF like

```
Select
Table1.PartSN,
Max(IIF(Table1.Test = 'Test1', Table1.Data, NULL)) As 'Test1',
Max(IIF(Table1.Test = 'Test2', Table1.Data, NULL)) As 'Test2'
From Table1 Group By Table1.PartSN
```

Data would be

```
PartSN Test1 Test2
Part1   20     23
```

Now my problem is that my test includes multiple iteration

```
PartSN Test Data Iter
Part1  Test1 20   1
Part1  Test2 23   1
Part1  Test1 19   2
Part1  Test2 24   2
```

Using my previous code, including iter in the IIF would only allow me to get one row but i need all iterations present like this:

```
PartSN Iter Test1 Test2
Part1   1    20     23
Part1   2    19     24
```

Thank you for any help or advice or link to a possible solution.

Comment: I suggest to use the **crosstab query wizard**. PartSN and Iter become row headings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider MS Access' unique crosstab query (unavailable in other DBMS) which avoids the line by line conditional aggregation expressions and automates the pivots across all *Test* values:

```
TRANSFORM Max(t.Data) As MaxData
SELECT t.PartSN, t.Iter
FROM mytable t
GROUP BY t.PartSN, t.Iter
PIVOT t.Test;

-- PartSN   Iter    Test1   Test2
-- Part1    1       20      23
-- Part1    2       19      24
```

Comment: Thanks for the introduction to Pivot! Reduced the query significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Just include it in the `select` and `group by`:

```
select t1.PartSN, t1.iter,
       max(iif(t1.Test = 'Test1', t1.Data, NULL)) As Test1,
       max(iif(t1.Test = 'Test2', t1.Data, NULL)) As Test2
from Table1 as t1
group by t1.PartSN, t1.iter;
```

Comment: Thanks! The code now outputs all data per iteration.